# What's the difference between "Thread.currentThread().getName" and "this.getName"?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is the code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;


class UnCatchExceptionThread extends Thread{
    public UnCatchExceptionThread(String name){
        this.setName(name);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread name is: " + this.getName());
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

class UnCatchExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler{
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("catch "  + e + " from " + t.getName());
    }
}

class HandlerFactory implements ThreadFactory{

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnCatchExceptionHandler());
        return t;
    }

}
public class CaptureException {

    public int i;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new HandlerFactory());
        exec.execute(new UnCatchExceptionThread("Gemoji"));
    }

}
```

And the output is:

> Thread name is: Gemoji 
>   catch java.lang.RuntimeException from Thread-1

If I changed the code

```
System.out.println("Thread name is: " + this.getName());
```

to

```
System.out.println("Thread name is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

The output will change to

> Thread name is: Thread-1 
>   catch java.lang.RuntimeException from Thread-1

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that at one moment, the UnCatchExceptionThread is passed to your `HandlerFactory.newThread()` method, and the thread returned by this method is executed. If so, you create a new thread with no name, that executes the runnable passed as argument. The runnable is the UnCatchExceptionThread instance, but the thread that is executing is the `new Thread(r)`.

So, inside the Runnable `run` method, `this` is the instance of UnCatchExceptionThread, and has the name you gave him. But the current thread is `new Thread(r)`, which has a default name.

Comment: I forget that `ThreadFactory` accept `Runnable` as param, and `Thread` also implements `Runnable`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The executor service is creating a thread "Thread-1" to run the run command from the given runnable. So the thread object name "Gemoji" is not the real thread being run.